# How to AES encrypt a link within Marketing Cloud and decrypt it in a third Party system

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, encryption, decrypt

I currently have the following problem: I am working in a Marketing Cloud Email and need some of my customers attributes to be stored in a Json and then to be aes-256 encrypted. The resulting string should then be a part of a link and decrypted by a third party system to use in their part of the customer journey.

I am currently struggling to find a way to encrypt the Json I created in a way that it can be decrypted by the third party system.

I tried using the EncryptSymmetric function with a password or with a symmetric key but I can’t seem to get the decryption done afterwards.

Is there a „best way“ on how to handle such a problem?

Thanks for any help.
Best regards,
Felix

Comment: You won't be able to do this with ampscript functions, because only ampscript can decipher ampscript (or ssjs). I would try to use the cloudpages url function and inside a cloudpage you can then code pretty standard and route towards your external system, if this makes sense.

Comment: This topic has already been discussed on SFSE a couple of times.  It's not recommended or supported by SFMC, but it can be done.